# Pandas calculate percent growth over rows

Tags: python, pandas

I've created the following pandas dataframe and try to calculate the growth in % between the years given in Col2:

| Col1 | Col2 | Jan | Feb | Mrz | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 600 |
| A | 2020 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 900 |
| B | 2019 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 60 |
| B | 2020 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 90 |
| C | 2019 | 1000 | 2000 | 3000 | 6000 |
| C | 2020 | 2000 | 3000 | 4000 | 9000 |

The table including the results should look like this (see last 3 rows):

| Col1 | Col2 | Jan | Feb | Mrz | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 600 |
| A | 2020 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 900 |
| B | 2019 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 60 |
| B | 2020 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 90 |
| C | 2019 | 1000 | 2000 | 3000 | 6000 |
| C | 2020 | 2000 | 3000 | 4000 | 9000 |
| A | GrowthInPercent | 100 | 50 | 33 | 50 |
| B | GrowthInPercent | 100 | 50 | 33 | 50 |
| C | GrowthInPercent | 100 | 50 | 33 | 50 |

Is there a way to calculate the GrowthInPercent values using a pandas function?

I do not get it ;-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) with `groupby`

```
u = (df[['Col1']].join(df.drop("Col2",1).groupby('Col1').pct_change()
     .mul(100).round())
     .dropna().assign(Col2="Growth%"))

out = df.append(u,ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
print(out)

  Col1     Col2     Feb     Jan     Mrz   Total
0    A     2019   200.0   100.0   300.0   600.0
1    A     2020   300.0   200.0   400.0   900.0
2    B     2019    20.0    10.0    30.0    60.0
3    B     2020    30.0    20.0    40.0    90.0
4    C     2019  2000.0  1000.0  3000.0  6000.0
5    C     2020  3000.0  2000.0  4000.0  9000.0
6    A  Growth%    50.0   100.0    33.0    50.0
7    B  Growth%    50.0   100.0    33.0    50.0
8    C  Growth%    50.0   100.0    33.0    50.0
```

**Note** - *this is assuming the data is sorted by `Col1` and `Col2` , if not you can use `df = df.sort_values(by=['Col1','Col2'])` first to sort the data*.

Comment: @TimR Glad I could help. Happy coding :-)